# How can I resolve an error related to PortAudio?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, portaudio

I am new to coding and I am doing a project using sound recognition and there is an error; when I try to write:

```
pip install port audio
```

It shows me this:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\nandith\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_q1bhzr0\\audio.coders\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\nandith\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_q1bhzr0\\audio.coders\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\nandith\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ruslt7j1'
         cwd: C:\Users\nandith\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_q1bhzr0\audio.coders\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\nandith\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_q1bhzr0\audio.coders\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import ConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? It says it cannot find ConfigParser. Try installing that module.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the package name of [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) was renamed to [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html).

**Change:**

```
import ConfigParser
```

**to:**

```
import configparser
```